# Android wifimanager.startscan() in main thread or in background?

Tags: android, android-wifi

What philosophy of startscan is better to use when i wanna get list of available wifi network?
I'm do this in main thread:

```
List<ScanResult> wifiList;
wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
wifiManager.startScan();
wifiList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
for (int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++) {
    String[] networkInfo = wifiList.get(i).toString().split(",");
    if (networkInfo[0].trim().equals(AP_SEARCH_SSID))
        petcub_networks++;
}
```

In all device which i'm use for test, it's work fine, except few samsung smartphone. It's happened on customer device and i can't debug it quickly. 
Is some one have same problem with samsung? Or will be better scan AP in background? Can it solve my problem?

**UPD:**Essence of my problem in next: i'm wanna scan available wifi networks, then if needs network was found i'm make connect to it(to socket). This procedure used in pipeline like first step.

Comment: What problem exactly? You should definitely register a receiver for `WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION` instead of calling `getScanResults()` immediately

Comment: U mean use this function in broadcast receiver?

Comment: Check my answer, it tackles the issue from several angles

Comment: Actually problem of my request stay more straight. Samsung device always return empty ssid name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to inform you but the code snippets had lots of missing elements (in term of efficiency) and is also incorrect, Let me elaborate this in points:

- startScan() only request a scan from the OS , it does not initiate a scan right away in some cases. so you need to check the return boolean from the call
- Before calling startScan you should register a BroadcastReceiver for WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION and only in after that even you should get the results
- You might not need to initiate a scan at a lot. a relatively fresh result may already be available. You can take a look on the timestamp value (API 17) of ScanResult to estimate how "fresh" the scan is
- You don't check if the device has WIFI hardware at all
- You only initiate a scan if the Wifi is on, Android devices (since API 16 I think) can scan for networks even if the WIFI is off
  To check if you can initiate a scan use this (In a function the returns boolean):

  ```
  if (!context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_WIFI)) {
      return false;
  }
  WifiManager mWifiManager = (WifiManager) context
          .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);


  boolean ret = mWifiManager.isWifiEnabled();
  ret = ret || ((android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) &&
          mWifiManager.isScanAlwaysAvailable());
  return ret;
  ```

Comment: I'm use 14 sdk as minimal. I'm check if wifi available. But most interest in that: i'm have this problem only on Samsung. WTF???It's so strange

Comment: Indeed, I agree with ceran